# GITLAB in debian 7

Tags: debian, gitlab

after reboot server, I've this error:

It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run

bundle install

If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following

```
Is this app supposed to be run as the git user?
Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.

-------- The exception is as follows: -------
Could not find rake-10.3.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:248:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:351:in `running_bundler'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:246:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.44/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

What's is my problem?.

Comment: The problem is solved by removing ruby1.9.1 and creating a symbolic link from /usr/local/bin/ruby ​​to /usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should ensure:

1. Did you set the PassengerRuby directive to point to the right Ruby version? I see you're using RVM, so PassengerRuby should point to a RVM-managed Ruby.
2. Did you bundle the gems in production mode inside the Gitlab directory?

   ```
   RAILS_ENV=production bundle install
   ```

I would definitely not mess with the Ruby installed under /usr/bin, it's perfectly fine if that's Ruby 1.9.1 as it's only required to run Passenger with. I'm assuming you've installed Passenger using the Debian packages?